# Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12 Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

In application i am passing data from one activity to other.On 2nd activity i am receiving this error

```
    06-18 11:32:58.187: W/dalvikvm(560): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project/com.example.project.edit_order}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3694)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1400)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1326)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:47)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:625)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at com.example.project.edit_order.onCreate(edit_order.java:42)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-18 11:32:58.217: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  ... 11 more
```

**FROM [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626102/caused-by-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-dimension) link i found that atleast one layout should pe**

```
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

**and my layout has this then also problem exist**

my XML IS

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background" >

<include layout="@layout/footer" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="460dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background2"
    android:minHeight="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bar" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:text="Order"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Oder ID"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/OrderId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/OrderPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/OrderDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Status"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/OrderStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/OrderTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="272dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bakery2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CancelOrder"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@id/back"
            android:text="Cancel Order" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626102/caused-by-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-dimension

Comment: yes i have menstioned in my question.

Comment: on what android os version your code crashes?

Comment: does this happens on a HTC device?

Comment: it happen on emulator

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822523/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-dimension-type-0x12)

Answer (score 0):

Use one Parent layout and put all XML code in that parent layout. I hope it solve your problem

Comment: i have only one parent layout which is relative Layout.