# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12

Tags: android, themes

I am getting this error, `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12`, from the following lines in my override of the `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` theme below using Android API 4.1.2.  It works fine in an older API and the newest.  What is the issue here?

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

I am using this users-sdk line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19"></uses-sdk>
```

Comment: Do you have mentioned any dimension in dimen file in your resources ? Please show your layout file code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822523/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-dimension-type-0x12)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**windowTranslucentNavigation**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowTranslucentStatus) and [**`windowTranslucentNavigation`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowTranslucentStatus)

Works Only for Api level `19` or above.Your setting the minSdkversion to `10`.

check the api level in the programmatically and set the

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
windowTranslucentNavigation=true;

}
```

Comment: Where is best place to do this?

Comment: can you elaborate the answer? @NambiNarayanan . When I place the code Android Studio is showing compilation errors on the line, windowTranslucentNavigation=true;